# "I could be something approaching myself''

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns, sentence-meaning

This sentence

> Partly this was because she was the only person on the island with whom I could be something approaching myself

is from John Harding, *The Girl Who Couldn’t Read* (2014). I can't understand the structure, nor the meaning. Is it that the narrator can be himself around her or what? And why is it put in such a strange manner, it's the first time I see something like that.

Comment: I read it like that too, yes, that the narrator can be almost himself. (Not _quite_ himself though, just an approximation.)

Comment: 'Partly this was because she was the only person on the island with whom I could really let my defences down and be the real me (well, almost).'

Comment: The twist that makes this ugly is  the *something approaching* modifying *myself*.*[S]he was the only person on the island with whom I could be myself* makes sense. It is poorly phrased.

Answer (score 1):

"Approaching" can literally mean "nearing", and in this kind of context it means "almost" or "only just".

For example, [this quote](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qP3XCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=%22approaching%20edible%22&source=bl&ots=Oz2p4GHLOP&sig=ACfU3U0aJhPS92y5gtE7Ve5sY2m5pXd98g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjm39qAwdXmAhWYO8AKHT0QDCYQ6AEwA3oECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22approaching%20edible%22&f=false):

> "It had been a while since I had been anywhere with food that I deemed *approaching edible*."

Here the author is describing food as "approaching edible" to mean it is *only just* worthy of eating.

So, in your example:

> Partly this was because she was the only person on the island with whom I could be something approaching myself.

This means that the first person has not been able to 'act like themself' with most people, but she has found someone with whom she can *almost* be like herself, ie she still has some reserve perhaps.